# How to change all spaces on span elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html:

```
<div>
    <div>Text1 Text2</div> 
    <div>
        Text2 
        <ul>
            <li>Text3</li>
        </ul>
        Text4 Text5
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to chage all spaces (**only in text nodes**) in all elements on `<span>.</span>`. The final html should looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div>Text1<span>.</span>Text2</div> 
    <div>
        Text2 
        <ul>
            <li>Text3</li>
        </ul>
        Text4<span>.</span>Text5
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i do it with jquery or without it?

Comment: Your question is totally wrong. You said you want to change ALL spaces. But your expected result doesn't show every space as <span> ... Only 2 of 150 spaces are changed to <span>. Are there any rules? Maybe you want to change just these spaces between two words?

Comment: @Adil, unfortunately, i have no idea how implement this, because of this i ask question.

Comment: @Wolle Vanillebär Lutz, sorry but where do you see another spaces in my html? I see only two

Comment: @Alexander There are obviously more spaces (e.g. at the beginning of the lines). You talk about the spaces that will actually be rendered.

Comment: @still_learning, yes, you are right. I changed question.

Comment: @Alexander Now it is correct :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one possible jQuery solution:

```
$('div *').contents().filter(function() {
    // get only non-empty text nodes
    return this.nodeType === 3
        && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
}).replaceWith(function() {
    // replace all spaces with the corresponding markup
    return $.trim(this.nodeValue).replace(/\s+/g, '<span>.</span>');
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9NL98/

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$('div').contents().each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    this.data = this.data.replace(/ /g, '<span>.</span>');
});
```